# "opensnoop" utility doesn't work with spaces between filenames, how to fix?

Tags: macos, unix

I use "opensnoop"

```
/usr/bin/opensnoop
```

to show all files which are opened from different processes.

But when I want to specific a file with

```
sudo opensnoop -n "directory/filename"
```

i'm getting this error:

```
token too large, exceeds YYLMAX
```

I'm hunting around for a fix and found only [this website](http://blog.brapi.net/2010/05/use-opensnoop-with-process-pane.html). The author modified the opensnoop script:

> this is due to line 154 in /usr/bin/opensnoop containing
>   inline string NAME  = "'$pname'";
>   that produces a dtrace script with this quoting
>   inline string NAME  = "foo' 'bar";
>   and the first single quote ends the dtrace invocation leaving its input script incomplete.
>   The quick patch is to replace line 154 with
>   inline string NAME  = "'"$pname"'";

but i'm still getting this error message.

Can anybody help me? Or tell me another utility where i can show the app which is currently working with a specific file?

Comment: `-n` is used to identify the process name to be snooped, why do you need a path for that?

Comment: @patrix For example `sudo opensnoop -n System\ Preferences` prints that same error, and -f doesn't work with paths that have spaces either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-n` is only meant to be used with process names like `sudo opensnoop -n System\ Preferences`. To see what processes access a file, use `sudo opensnoop -f /tmp/a\ b.txt`.

The change mentioned in the blog post fixes -n but not -f. To fix both of them, edit `/usr/bin/opensnoop` and replace these lines:

```
inline string PATHNAME = "'$pathname'";
inline string NAME = "'$pname'";
```

With this:

```
inline string PATHNAME = "'"$pathname"'";
inline string NAME = "'"$pname"'";
```

Comment: Thank's! But, for example, when i open up a screenshot via Preview, and opensoop -n "Screenshot", no processes are shown. Shouldn't there been the "Preview-Process"?

Comment: You're supposed to use something like `sudo opensnoop -f ~/Pictures/Screenshot.png`.

Comment: Ahhh....how stupid could i be... sure! Thank's very much! RTFM... :)